# How do I get measures on mouse down in?

Tags: c#, xaml, infragistics

I am using XamDataChart and I have to get current chart measures on the mouse down event.

I've tryed to put the mouse down event on the `BarSeries` but I still can't find a way to get a measure that corelate with this `BarSeries` object:

```
    xmBarSeries.MouseLeftButtonDown += XmBarSeriesOnMouseLeftButtonDown;

    private void XmBarSeriesOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
    {
        var barSeries = (()sender);            
    }
```

Another words: 
I simply click on the chart (in some point) and get current measure (a year 1209 on X axis and the cost 12345$ on Y axis)

Comment: Use the vendor's support channels to find help.  Like http://forums.infragistics.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the SeriesMouseLeftButtonDown event:

http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/DV/2011.2/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsSL4.Controls.Charts.XamDataChart.v11.2~Infragistics.Controls.SeriesViewer~SeriesMouseLeftButtonDown_EV.html

Comment: How comes the SeriesMouseLeftButtonUp event is not fired?